# Do I Need To Use A Nested Array? How Do I Set It Up? - Groovy

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, groovy, initialization, datastore

I will want to record specific dates and the events taking place on them, but they do not all have the same number of events.

Here are some examples of the dates I'd like to record and their events:

- Date: "10.31.18"  Events: "Halloween", "Dad's Birthday".
- Date: "11.22.18"  Events: "Thanksgiving"
- Date: "7.25.18"  Events: "Mom's Birthday", "Dalton's Birthday", "Mark's Birthday"

What is the best way to record this data? I was thinking it would be an array, but what would that look like?

Comment: It is my first post so let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: What you want is an map from date to set of events. In java, that would be Map<Date, Set<String>>, but I don't know Groovy syntax. This question is not quite what SO is intended for, though. Look at [these upvoted/answered groovy questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgroovy%5D+score%3A1+hasaccepted%3Ayes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way you wrote it, it would be just plain `Map<String, List<String>>` which in groovy is:

```
def events = [
    "10.31.18": ["Halloween", "Dad's Birthday"],
    "11.22.18": ["Thanksgiving"],
    "7.25.18":  ["Mom's Birthday", "Dalton's Birthday", "Mark's Birthday"]
]
```

To put an empty list into this map you need to:

```
events."10.31.19" = []
```

Better idea is to use `Date` as a key instead of plain of `String`, e.g.

```
def events = [:]
events.(new Date().parse("dd.MM.yyyy","22.03.2019")) = []
```

And IMHO the best idea is to do some OOP create a class named `DatedEvents` which will have to fields: `Date date` and `List<String> events` and use this class as a storage.